# How to read Windows environment variables on dotnet core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a Web API using dotnet core 3.1 and now I got into the need to store a kind of sensitive information on a Windows Environment variable which I already did. Let's call it MY_WIN_VAL_X.

I tried to use the following code on the ConfigureServices method on the Startup.cs ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8))

```
public class Startup
{
    private IHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;

        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ...other code
       var myEnvValX = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_WIN_VAL_X");
    }
}
```

However, I got this error:

> 'IHostEnvironment' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetEnvironmentVariable' and no accessible extension method
>   'GetEnvironmentVariable' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IHostEnvironment' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?) [API]csharp(CS1061)

Does anyone knows how to achieve it? How to get the custom Windows environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the environment variables is done via the [Configuration mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#environment-variables), and therefore are accessible via the `IConfiguration` object rather than the `IHostEnvironment` object.

To add the environment variables to your configuration, you'll need to add this to your `Program.cs` file:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables(); // <-- this line
                // optional: use a prefix
                //config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "MYPREFIX_"); // <-- this line
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

And then you can read your environment variable like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    private IHostEnvironment Environment { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;

        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       ...other code
       var myEnvValX = this.Configuration["MY_WIN_VAL_X"];
    }
}
```

Note that you can restrict which environment variables are available by prefixing them. For example, if you have `MYPREFIX_MY_WIN_VAL_X`, `MYPREFIX_MY_WIN_VAL_Y`, you can restrict the env variables with `config.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "MYPREFIX_")`, and only those two variables will be exposed (the prefix will be removed).